# CSS to bold a varying length section of a paragraph up to a delimiter like a colon or hyphen

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to apply a bold style to the beginning of a paragraph up to a  delimiter character--like a colon or hyphen? The value before the delimiter can be any length.

So a string like this:

Definition item: description or definition of the item....

would look like:

**Definition item:** description or definition of the item....

Comment: No. CSS can't read your content like that. You;d need to wrap that text in a element like a span and style that.

Comment: Just because this can be done (with js or other tools) doesn't mean that it should be. I think you may want to consider how the markup is generated before attempting to implement this type of a solution

Comment: CSS only offers the pseudo class `:first-letter` and `:first-line` to style text partially.  To bold a text to emphase it, you can use the <em> or <strong> tag, <b> is also avalaible but that is HTML to structure your text.

Answer (score 2):

I get this result in javascript but its impossible to make in css :
( updated and added while loop )

```js
function myFunction(str) {
    var res = str.split(":");
    var mynewres = "<b>" + res[0] + ": " + "</b>" + res[1];
    var i = 2;
    var newres = mynewres;
    while (typeof res[i] !== 'undefined') {
        newres = newres + ":" + res[i];
        i++;
    }
    return newres;
}

var newtxt = myFunction("Note: This Function Don't Work Correctly If No Colones Are Used! That Means : You Must Use One Colone At Least!");
document.getElementById("LookHere").innerHTML = newtxt;
```

```css
#LookHere {
font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span id="LookHere">
```

Comment: Why Does He Have To Be A Pro To Use A While Loop? Why Capitalize Every Word?

Comment: for nothing but its need some smart

Answer (score 1):

to add to my earlier comment :

> CSS only offers the pseudo class `:first-letter` and `:first-line` to style text partially.  To bold a text to emphase it, you can use the `<em>` or `<strong>` tag. `<b>` is also avalaible but that is HTML to structure your text.

For what it seems, there is an HTML structure to use that will describe itself these text content: [the definition list(W3C) `<dl><dt><dd>`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/dl)

> The `<dl>` element represents a description list.

```css
dt {font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Definition item:</dt>
    <dd>description or definition of the item....</dd>
</dl>
```

add some styles to set it on a line

```css
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}

dt,
dd {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Definition item:</dt>
  <dd>description or definition of the item....</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your title with `<b></b>`

```html
<span><b>Definition item:</b> description or definition of the item....<span>
```

Also, you can use JS to handle this. (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

Just because this can be done does not mean that you should do this.

Manipulating the DOM just to change display is very bad practice.

Concern should be given to how the info is being generated in the first place.

That said here is a solution using jquery

```js
$('p').each(function(e){
var title = this.innerText.substring(0, this.innerText.indexOf(':'))
var definition = this.innerText.substring(this.innerText.indexOf(':')).replace(":","").trim()
console.log("title:"+title);
console.log("definition:"+definition);
$(this).html("<strong>"+title+":</strong> "+definition)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Definition item: description or definition of the item....</p>
<p>another item: description or definition of the item....</p>
<p>new item: description or definition of the item....</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Allthough you should just edit it directly in the html. Here a jQuery free and flexible javascript solution:

```js
var definitions = document.querySelectorAll('.definition');
for (var i = 0; i < definitions.length; i++) {
    definitions[i].innerHTML = definitions[i].innerText.replace(/^[^:]+:/, '<b>$&</b>');
}
```

```html
<p class=definition>Definition: This is something.</p>
<p class=definition>Example: Also allows : after definition.</p>
```

For the regex. ^ is the beginning of the string, [^:] matches everything not a colon +, for more than one match and ending with matching the colon itself, $& substitutes the match back in.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const boldStringInAnotherString = (mainString, boldString) => {
  const splitted = mainString.split(boldString)

  return !mainString.includes(boldString) ? (<span>mainString</span>)
    : (<span>{splitted[0]}<b>{boldString}</b>{splitted[1]}</span>)
}
```