# What does this .replace(/^[^:]+:/, '<b>$&</b>') regex mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to make a code that can make my HTML list to be bold. But it needs to be bold in the beginning until it reached a colon. So I searched for a code that I chould would help me out. And saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46855744/15163136) code from stack overflow. But instead of using a for loop I used a foreach loop.

```
<ul>
 <li>Apple: Has the color red</li>
 <li>Orange: Has the color orange</li>
 <li>Banana: Has the color yellow</li>
 <li>Blackberries: Has the color purple</li>
 <li>Avocado: Has the color green</li>
</ul>

 <script type="text/javascript">

   let list = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
   list.forEach((element) => {
     element.innerHTML = element.innerText.replace(/^[^:]+:/, '<b>$&</b>');
     
 </script>
```

It works great! But I don't understand what the `/^[^:]+:/` and `'<b>$&</b>'` mean or do.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's a [regex pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: [https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5B%5E%3A%5D%2B%3A%2F](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5B%5E%3A%5D%2B%3A%2F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^[^:]+:/` and `<b>$&</b>`
The first part is a regular expression.  You can see regular expressions often  wrapped in `/ /`. Regular expressions describe patterns to be matched inside a string. Different symbols mean different things depending on the context.

If a regular expression starts with a `^` this means that the pattern has to match from the start of the string.  The start of the innerText would be the A  in  'Apple:... '

Next we have the `[^:]+`.  The square brackets describe characters we are looking for. So `[a-z]` would mean match every lower case character. Here instead of a-z, we have `^:`. Inside the character brackets, `^` means `not`, so  `[^:]` means find any character that is not a colon.  A `+` after finding something means find 1 or more of these.  So, `[^:]+` means find 1 or more characters that are not `:`.

Next we have a `:`, which means find a colon.  So, to read the whole regular expression, `/^[^:]+:/` - from the start of the string find every character that is not a colon, then find a colon.  If it finds this, it is considered a match.

The `<b>$&</b>` describes what to do with the match. If you wrote in this second argument `Item -` , then every line would get rid of the fruit name and replace it like this `Item -  Has the color red`. Here `$&` means 'use the thing we matched'.  So this takes the whole match and wraps it in `<b>..</b>`, making it bold.

Answer (score 0):

`/^[^:]+:/` it match any characters from the start of string till first match of `:` replace it with itself(`$&`) but surrounded by
**`<b>`** tag to make it **bold**

```js
"<li>Apple: Has the color red</li>".replace(/^[^:]+:/, '<b>$&</b>');
```

result `<li><b>Apple:</b> Has the color red</li>`

Comment: How do you know this? Is there a site to read what each of `^`, `[^:]` and `$%` means?

Comment: @Bennpoes yes, just paste it in to https://regex101.com/

Comment: Yeah, I studied regex at university and you mean this '$&' it is a backreference to the whole match.